# Printing Recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have this class the just prints an int:

```
class PRecursion  {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
       foo(1);
 }

public static void foo(int x){
    System.out.println("" + x);

    if (x < 3)
        foo(x+1);
    System.out.println(""+x);   
   }

}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
```

Why is it the is printing backwards then decrements?

Comment: A little hint: If the question has been answered, it is usefull for everyone (especially people searching for this problem in the future) if you _mark the question as answered_ by accepting an answer. Just a reminder ;)

Answer (score 4):

It is not actually decrementing. What is happening is:

- You are calling `foo(1)`.
- `foo(1)` does it's thing and starts a *recursion*.
- Recursion goes on for how long you tell it to (`foo(3)` in your example)
- After the recursion is done, `foo(1)` still has one statement to execute, and that is:

  `System.out.println(""+x);`

hence you are seeing the print of `foo(1)` a second time, but after all other prints have been made. The same goes for every other time `foo()` is being called with a different number. So in the end it looks like it is decrementing, when really you are only *printing a second time for the same value, in **reverse order***.

Answer (score 3):

The value of x is not decrementing but it executes the remaining part of code which looks like decrementing.

```
  System.out.println(" " + x);   // 1 2 3

    if (x < 3)
        foo(x+1);
  System.out.println(""+x);   //3 2 1
```

due to recursion it calls the same function again and again and print only the first print statement until the `if` condition is true but at the end when `if` is false it stop executing `foo(x+1)` and exute the remaining print statements as the execution in the last step x is 3 so it prints `3 2 1` .

Maybe this could clear a bit more

---

[image: Execution flow]

---

Since all the `foo(1)-->foo(2)-->foo(3)` is executed causing output `1 2 3` the execution is in the last method `foo(3)` so it started executing the remaining method statement with flow like `foo(3)-->foo(2)-->foo(1)` printing the remaining print statement which executes looks like all the function backwards resulting in remaining `3 2 1`.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply.. but could you explain more.. I dont understand why the second print statement decrements the input?

Comment: .. that diagram shows a more clear explanation..thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class PRecursion  {
    public static void main(String[] args){     
       foo(1);
 }

public static void foo(int x){
    System.out.println("before " + x);

    if (x < 3)
        foo(x+1);
    System.out.println("after "+x);   
   }

}
```

The second print statement doesn't decrement the input. What is happening is it leaves the call of `foo(3)` before it leaves the call of `foo(2)` and then finally `foo(1). So it executes the second print statements in the reverse of the order of the first.

If you read out the execution of the program as:

```
set x=1
print x (i.e. 1)
push x=1 on stack and set x=2 (this is how you can read foo(x+1))
print x (i.e. 2)
push 2 on stack and set x=3
print x (i.e. 3)
Don't push anything (x<3 is false)
print x again (i.e. 3)
pop x=2 off the stack
print x (i.e. 2)
pop x=1 of the stack
print x (i.e. 1)
```

stripping out the pushing and popping you get:

```
print 1
print 2
print 3
print 3
print 2
print 1
```

Comment: That's Perfect. So when the function returns from the call stack at that time it has got the value of X as 3 , 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: Hey.. Thanks that makes sense to me now.. I think it has something to do with stacks isn't...

Comment: @NoobProgrammer It has a lot to do with stacks... I've extended the answer to try and show that.